# I don't understand why this is causeing my program to crash?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I don't understand why this is causing my program to crash!? when i compile it makes it to then end of the program then stops responding.

```
void rotate90(Image& image)
{
    Pixel * tempPixel = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
    for(int r = 0; r < image.infoHeader.biHeight; r ++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < image.infoHeader.biWidth; c++)
        {

            int f = c+(r*image.infoHeader.biWidth);
            int t = (image.infoHeader.biHeight - r - 1) + (image.infoHeader.biWidth-c-1);
            tempPixel[t] = image.pixels[f];
        }
    }
    image.pixels =tempPixel ;
    delete[] tempPixel;
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to edit the question... you should add the information about the new problem you encountered *after* the old question body, otherwise current answers become seemingly unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare that variable before using it...

```
Pixel * tempPixel = new Pixel[image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight];
```

Notice that you must deallocate the temporary array at the end of the function with `delete[]` (otherwise you have a memory leak). To make this automatic and avoid issues with exception safety, you should be using a smart pointer, like `scoped_array<Pixel>` from Boost or (if you have a compiler that supports the new C++ standard) `unique_ptr<Pixel[]>`.

Even better: you could just use a `std::vector<Pixel>`

```
std::vector<Pixel> tempPixel(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight);
```

and let it deal with allocation/deallocation.

---

Preemptive answer correction (due to your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424672/why-does-my-program-crash-when-i-attempt-to-run-this)): if in the end you are going to assign `tempPixel` to `image.pixels`, then you must not `delete[]` `tempPixel`, otherwise `image` will be replaced with a pointer to deallocated memory.

But you have bigger problems: when you replace `image.pixels` you are not deallocating the memory it was pointing to previously. So you should deallocate *that* memory and *then* assign `tempPixel` to it.

All this assuming that `image.pixels` was allocated with `new` and is going to be deallocated with `delete[]` (otherwise you get a mismatch of allocation functions/operators).

---

By the way, if your image is just some kind of wrapper for a Windows DIB (BMP) as it seems from the header fields names you are not taking into account the fact that pixel lines are 4-byte aligned (so, if your image is not 32bpp, you must allocate more memory and perform the pixel copy accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

change array declaration

```
tempPixel[] = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
```

to

```
Pixel* tempPixel = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
```

and remember to delete it with

```
delete[] tempPixel;
```