# why does my program crash when i attempt to run this?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need help declaring a temarary array to hold a bitmap picture while i rotate it 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424303/i-need-help-declaring-a-temarary-array-to-hold-a-bitmap-picture-while-i-rotate-i)

why does my program crash when i attempt to run this?
Also on the end of line 10(+ (image.infoHeader.biWidth-c-1);) of the code is not working the way i want it to; do you see what wrong with it?

```
void rotate90(Image& image)
{
    Pixel * tempPixel = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
    for(int r = 0; r < image.infoHeader.biHeight; r ++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < image.infoHeader.biWidth; c++)
        {

            int f = c+(r*image.infoHeader.biWidth);
            int t = (image.infoHeader.biHeight - r - 1) + (image.infoHeader.biWidth-c-1);
            tempPixel[t] = image.pixels[f];
        }
    }
    tempPixel = image.pixels;
    delete[] tempPixel;
}
```

Comment: no it is not; its a fix to that question with an actual question now

Comment: You should edit your existing question!

Comment: No it didn't; follow the link...

Comment: By the way, you should have mentioned in the previous question that you were going to swap the pointers in the end, my suggestion about the `delete[]` would have been different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
tempPixel = image.pixels;
delete[] tempPixel;
```

You overwrite the pointer you got from `new` with a different address. Then you call `delete[]` on the pointer which now points to memory owned by the `image` object.